# how to find number of working days for particular month in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having problem in calculating number of working days for particular month. I have attendance model.which contains, school_id,course_id,section_id,student_id,attendance_date attributes.These fields for making attendance for particular section in particular school

For viewing attendance report, I have school,course,section and month fields.when I select the month it will show the number of working days for that particular month.So, I have to calculate working days by attendance_date field from attendance model. I am having confusion in that. Please help me.

Comment: So what is your problem? To get the list of working days in a month? Do you need only days that are monday-friday or you additionally need to exclude official country holidays from that list?

Comment: To list number of working days in a particular month.some week Saturday also working day.so,how to calculate working days.

Comment: I think you should make a separate table listing all days in a year with a flag working and not working and fill it with your specific data. As working/not working can be different per country and per year, like in U.S. there are official holidays that are only celebrated once in 4 years, other countries like Ukraine or Russia have an easter the date of which can be different from year to year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [business_time](https://github.com/bokmann/business_time)

Example:

```
4.business_days.from_now
8.business_days.after(some_date)
```